# How can I have the equivalent of an onClick in an onPress in React/ React Native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to use scrollTo https://reactjsexample.com/scroll-to-a-position-in-react but I need an onClick in order to do so. I also want to place it inside a Text and I can only use onPress.
While I could create a View, it would not have the same visual effect, I want the hand cursor to show up when I am hovering over the View.
Does anyone know how to use ScrollTo with onPress or how to have the hand above the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the hand over the input you can use css styles, it's very simple to do, just place this in your StyleSheet:

```
cursor: pointer;
```

In order to use ScrollTo you just have to follow the tutorial that you linked. If you want to do it for react-native then you won't be able to have the hand icon but to scroll you would use the reanimated library and do something like this: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/nativeMethods/scrollTo/